# C# says this.Controls is null, why?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, designer, nullreferenceexception

Earlier my code was running nicely.. then I edited some .. did not touch the designer code.

[alt text http://img718.imageshack.us/img718/3759/errorstack.jpg](http://img718.imageshack.us/img718/3759/errorstack.jpg)

Why this error is being shown?

Comment: Could it be that label1 is null instead?

Comment: what is null exactly?  Controls?  or label1?

Comment: check your code properly !!! might be changed any control id or !!! :)

Comment: Oh sorry, this.Control is null. refer: http://img260.yfrog.com/img260/3759/errorstack.jpg

Comment: I am sorry. I made one variable called Controls (ArrayList)... extreamly sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If this is Windows Forms - did you remove the InitializeComponent() line from the form's constructor?

Comment: I am sorry. I made one variable called Controls (ArrayList)... extreamly sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its the label is Null and that's causing the trouble. I'm not that experienced with C# but it could be the case that Controls doesn't except a Null-Pointer.

Comment: I am sorry. I made one variable called Controls (ArrayList)... extreamly sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, at this point in code label1 is not yet initialized.
Whic event handler are you coding this in ? Make sure controls are initialized before using them.
Make sure you are using the controls after InitComplete event.

Comment: I am sorry. I made one variable called Controls (ArrayList)... extreamly sorry.